# Simple image metadata reading using .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, imagesharp

I have seen seen several posts regarding this but I could not apply any of them. It's perhaps due to documentation change. I used ImageSharp and System.Drawings.
System.Drawings is not supported in .Net Core. Also ImageSharp sample that I found did not work.( I am not a C# expert)

This is what I used to get the metadata using Imagesharp

```
using (Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load(input))
{
   var exif = image.MetaData.ExifProfile.GetValue;

   var met = exif.GetValue(SixLabors.ImageSharp.MetaData.Profiles.Exif.ExifTag.ImageDescription);   
}
```

the problem is that I get null for `exif` variable ( I am not sure what I am doing wrong). Is there a simple code sample that I can use to do this? I tried to read the doc here https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.MetaData.Profiles.Exif.ExifProfile.html but I could not figure out how to use it. Any help would be appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is wrong:

> var exif = image.MetaData.ExifProfile.GetValue;

Just remove the `.GetValue` from the end as you are referencing a method here.

So

```
using (var image = Image.Load(input))
{
   var exif = image.MetaData.ExifProfile;
   var met = exif.GetValue(SixLabors.ImageSharp.MetaData.Profiles.Exif.ExifTag.ImageDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the image you supplied to the program does not have associated EXIF data. I used an image from a Photography site which had valid EXIF info, it was properly parsed by the library.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
var exif = image.Metadata.ExifProfile.Values;
foreach (var value in exif)
{
    list.Add($"{value.Tag.ToString()}--{value.DataType.ToString()}");

}
```